# Is there a straight way to get html response from a unix socket in Go (like curl does)?

Tags: sockets, curl, go, docker, docker-swarm

I need to create a docker (1.13) container that will be running as a service in a docker swarm to schedule jobs (like a swarm-wide crontab that performs 'docker exec' where needed).
I'm a rather sysadmin guy and not really a coder, so I started doing it with with bash, curl and jq.
It works, but there is definitely room for improvement.

To give you an idea of the mumbo-jumpo I'm dealing with, here are a few snippets of the calls I pass to the docker socket to find out where the services are running:

```
# Get local docker node ID:
curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.26/info | jq -r '.Name + " " + .Swarm.NodeID'

# List swarm node ID's:
curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.26/nodes | jq -r '.[] | .Description.Hostname + " " + .ID'

# List swarm services:
curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.26/nodes | jq -r '.[] | .Description.Hostname + " " + .ID'

# List running tasks:
curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.26/tasks | jq -r '.[] | select( .Status.State | contains("running")) | .NodeID + " " + .ServiceID + " " + .ID + " " + .Status.State'
```

I'd like to do it nicer with **golang**.

I understand how http.Get works when talking to a tcp socket:

```
res, err := http.Get(url)
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &p)
// p is then populated with the content of my request
```

But how can I deal with a unix filesocket (/var/run/docker.sock)? I assume I have to use **net.DialUnix** but could not get it to work so far.

Any idea or suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Use the client API - https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/getting-started/#tab-run-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "log"
    "bufio"

)

func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("unix", "/var/run/docker.sock")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "GET /images/json HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
    status, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\t')
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Print("Message from server: "+status)
}
```

Another approach:

Use [docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/getting-started/), available for python, go and some other languages.